# Im getting this waring (React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either include it or remove the dependency )

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProduct = async () => {
           const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/product/${match.params.id}`)

           setProduct(data)
        }

        fetchProduct()
    }, [])
```

Comment: Well, the error speaks for itself! You need to include `match.params.id` in your `useEffect` dependency array :)
`useEffect(() => ..., [match.params.id])`

Comment: thankyou for help as Im newb to react so didnt figured it out ^^